Pressing left or right CTRL presses a number of other keys activating multiple shortcuts at once
when I press Control a number of other keys get registered as pressed, activating different shortcuts and preventing me from using the shortcut i want to use. the additional keys pressed are different between the two CTRL's and its only the Control keys with this issue.
the left CTRL presses F3, F6, F8, Tab, t, y, [, and ].
the right CTRL presses , a, s, d, f, j, k, l, ;, and return.
I'm running Kubuntu on a Asus 202SA Chromebook with the MrCromeBox custom firmware.
